# prevent jtable column from resizing after certain value is exceeded

Tags: java, swing, jtable, propertychangelistener

I have a jtable having a total column width of X pixels.

I want to prevent any column in that jtable from resizing when the total width exceeds that X pixels.

I tried PropertyChangeListener and other custom implementations in vain.

Comment: Technically, you have to set the maxWidth of each table column. But suspect that's not what you really want :-) So please show a SSCCE that demonstrates what you have tried and how it doesn't fulfill your requirement.

Comment: provide your example code and specify your problem, now that's really wide.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set `AUTO_RESIZE_OFF` and you can manually handle the width for any column in JTable like:

```
table.setAutoResizeMode(JTable.AUTO_RESIZE_OFF);
table.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setPreferredWidth(123);
table.getColumnModel().getColumn(1).setPreferredWidth(250);
table.getColumnModel().getColumn(2).setPreferredWidth(123);
table.getColumnModel().getColumn(3).setPreferredWidth(125);
```

Comment: Seriously ? This does not answer my question

Comment: @jadk So what you want?

Comment: I have an original jtable total width 100. I want to listen to column resize. If after resize the total column width exceeds 100, discard this resize. Your answer doesn't meet the requirements. But thanks anyways

Comment: Edit your question and try to give more details about your problem. Reading your second line in question i can just say that you have to use `AUTO_RESIZE_OFF`.